# What is the correct usage for 'nominate'?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Can one say "have you nominated" or would you require an object, "have you nominated yourself"?

Context is that of an election, for example.

Comment: I always find it helpful to take a look at http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/ for some context. Here is an example of use of the word nominate: "Before President XXX even announced he was going to nominate Sonia XXXXX to the Supreme Court, conservatives promised a tough confirmation battle" (Source: CBS News).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, *nominate* is *usually* transitive and thus requires an object ("I nominated someone"). However, there are a few exceptions in which the verb is intransitive:

- intr. Austral. Polit. To put oneself forward formally as a candidate for election; to register one's candidacy. Usu. with for.
- Snooker and Pool. To specify (a ball) as the object ball to be hit next by the cue ball; (also in Pool) to indicate (the set of balls) as the set one will aim to pot; to specify (a pocket) into which one is aiming the next ball. Also intr.
- trans. To choose (a mare) as suitable for mating to a particular stallion. Also intr. with to.

Thus, in the context of an election it can usually be expected to require an object. However, there are a few cases in which this is not true.

Comment: It looks like your first point is the meaning intended here.

Comment: So I guess the answer is, in a nutshell, “It’s fine in Australia, but probably not elsewhere.”

Answer (score 3):

It is a transitive verb, so would seem to require an object.

> Have you nominated anyone?

is how I would put it.

Answer (score 0):

When using it in the passive tense, it doesn't take an object.

> Have you ever been nominated for a Grammy award?